# using Neo4j embedded in Java applications

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-embedded

I am trying to use Neo4j embedded in Java applications, and I am using this code:

```
package com.tp.neo4j.java.examples;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
public class Neo4jJavaAPIDBOperation {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/TPNeo4jDB");
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
        // Perform DB operations    
        tx.success();
    }   
 }
}
```

But I got this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method newEmbeddedDatabase(File) in the type GraphDatabaseFactory is not applicable for the arguments (String)
    Syntax error on token ";", try expected after this token
```

any idea, please

Comment: the method `newEmbeddedDatabase` requires a `File`, code is passing a `String`... try `...newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("C:/TPNeo4jDB"));`

Comment: I got :
File cannot be resolved to a type @Carlos Heuberger

Comment: you need to to `import java.io.File`

Comment: Yes,, it works, Thanks alot

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`newEmbeddedDatabase` expect `File` as argument

```
GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("C:/TPNeo4jDB"));
```